# Cannot run apt-get autoremove because disk is full

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, disk-usage

I'm in a desperate situation. We have this ubuntu virtual machine with very low disk space:

```
du -sch /*
```

This is the most significant:

```
7,7G total
3,6g /usr
2,4g /lib
508M /boot
270M /home
256M /var
```

apt-get autoremove fails because the disk is full. Any ideas on what can we do to free up some space?

Also cannot access hidden folders in /home because disk is full

Comment: What is the out put of these three command? `du -hs /var/cache/apt/archives/ 2> /dev/null` , `ls /boot/init* -lh` , `df -h` . [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1059706/edit) your question and add these outputs to your question.

Comment: TBH 7-8GB is not much space to be running Ubuntu. As minimum I'd provide 20 GB. And why run Ubuntu in a VM unless you're just testing it out anyway? If the system is that important to you then it should be on your hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your issue here is that you're not sure what would be safe to delete given that you can't check the things in `/home` and can't run `apt-get autoremove`.

Depending on the machine uptime and setup you may be able to free up some space by deleting some logs from `/var/log` which will generally be safe to delete and can take a decent chunk of space (over 100M on my laptop atm). You can use `rm /var/log/foo.log` as suggested in another answer.